# How do I do an image swap with radio buttons, 3 images and 3 states?

Tags: jquery, image, radio-button, swap

I have 3 images that need to switch to `on state` when each of 3 radio buttons are clicked - and back when they are not checked.

Simple enough: 
The value associated with the radio buttons is the id of the image and the name of the image ( minus the state ).

Which I hope to tie to the image `src` when the button is clicked.
How do I get this to work?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $(".challengeradio").change(function(){
          if(this.checked){  
             $("#" + this.value +".pic").attr("src").replace("_off", "_on");     
                          }     
                   });     
          });
```

~~~ and the requested XHTML~

```
 <div id="chooseChallenge">
    <h2> Choose a Challenge </h2>
    <div class="badge" id="weightLossChallenge"> 
    <div class="challengelabel" id="chall_weightloss">
    <input type="radio" value="chall_weightloss" name="challenge" class="challengeradio">
   <strong> the big <br>Thang</strong>
    </div>
    <img border="0" src="http://www.yoozit.net/zone/images/chall_weightloss_on.png" id="chall_weightloss" class="pic"> </div>

    <div class="badge" id="activityChallenge">
     <div class="challengelabel" id="chall_activity">
    <input type="radio" value="chall_activity" name="challenge" class="challengeradio">
    <strong> Activity Tracker<br>Thang</strong>
    </div> <img border="0" src="http://www.yoozit.net/zone/images/chall_activity_off.png" id="chall_activity" class="pic"></div>

    <div class="badge" id="basicChallenge"> 
    <div class="challengelabel" id="chall_basic">
    <input type="radio" value="chall_basic" name="challenge" class="challengeradio">
    <strong>Basic Standard <br>Thang</strong>
    </div>
    <img border="0" src="http://www.yoozit.net/zone/images/chall_basic_off.png" id="chall_basic" class="pic"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Which language is this - perhaps add a tag for it? Also best to highlight the text that is code and click the code sample button {} just above the edit box.

Comment: @ ChrisBD sorry - jquery

Comment: Could you post your html as well please .

Comment: @Frank Astin sure here you go

Comment: @AnthonyDeoIsm Not sure if it's exactly what you want ; but check this fiddle  : http://jsfiddle.net/2Sy2h/

Comment: @Frank Astin - THANK YOU SIRE - this works great for single image - and SHOULD work for multiple - I took the liberty of adding another image to the array - and ..... no dice :(  - I know I must be missing something - I've updated your fiddle :) lovely site!! and cannot understand why it's not working - now adding alerts to display what javascript is 'seeing'

Answer (score 0):

Try using $(this).checked, $(this).value

```
$(".challengeradio").click(function() {
    $("#" + $(this).val() +".pic").attr("src").replace("_off", "_on");   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("img.addToFavourite").live('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr("class") == "addToFavourite") {
      this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
      this.title="Remove from favourite"
    } else {
      this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
      this.title="Add to favourite"
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
  });
```

there are two image with name `favourite_off.png` and `favourite_on.png`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kJjxC/)

Comment: please - the radio button should trigger the image replacement - precisely - @diEcho - you removed my radio button :)

Comment: I have just suggested you the logic. rest of all is in your hand. you can check the radio button by `$.prop('checked')`

Comment: i have made this work every other way but with the radio.  is there some conflict im not aware of wth the radio object?

Comment: hey is the .onLive{} in the css needed for anything?

Answer (score 0):

Done!

Bit hacky but does the job :

http://jsfiddle.net/2Sy2h/26/

The code :

```
  $(".challengeradio").change(function(){

           if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
          previous = $('img.onlive').first();
          previnput = $('input.onlive').first();

          var preimgsrc = {};
          preimgsrc['src'] = "http://www.yoozit.net/zone/images/"+ previnput.attr('value') + "_off.png" ;
          previous.attr(preimgsrc).removeClass('onlive');
          previnput.removeClass('onlive');
          var imgsrc = {};
          imgsrc['src'] = "http://www.yoozit.net/zone/images/"+ this.value + "_on.png" ;  


          $("#" + this.value +".pic").attr(imgsrc).addClass('onlive');
          $(this).addClass('onlive')   
              }            
            });
```

Comment: you jedi MASTER!!! you life saver(I fall to my knees and wait in the snow for you to accept me as your padwan learner!!) Thanks a bunch

Comment: No probs , could you mark the question as answered so I get my rep points /

Comment: Slight change to the code , I forgot to remove the onlive class after extracting the prev img name . Works perfectly now .